# Hover affecting only single element in nested set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't change the following HTML structure which has nested `<div>` elements that all have the same class `block`. I want to enable a hover behavior that only affects the element that the mouse is over at the moment, not any of the other nested elements.

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block">
                Text
            </div>
            Text
        </div>
        Text
    </div>
    Text
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/FqKCY/3/

I tried to use this:

```
$( ".block" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
    }, function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
    }
);
```

But it didn't help. Maybe I shall add `if` statement with `.hasClass` checker?

Is the effect I'm trying for possible?

Comment: I think it has to do with event propagation. Since the inner divs are children of another div which receives the class on hover, the outer div will still have the same class because you're still hovering on it, event though you're targeting only the child. Mind if you just separate these divs?.

Comment: @jacelysh it works if I change the markup a bit, yes, but what if I need to preserve current structure of the markup?

Comment: Have you considered the [:hover css pseudo class](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/h/hover/) Here is a jsfiddle I made a while back with nested divs and hovers: http://jsfiddle.net/waltbosz/paTE9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution utilizes the `.hover()` function you started with. A better solution might be to write your own handler that prevents event propagation using `.on()`. You'll note that the text for the entire stack is changed because the .css inherits, but you could modify the .css so that this doesn't happen.

The technique used is to remove all hovering on entry, and then apply it only to the current element. On exit remove from all, and then only apply to a parent element if it exists.

```
$(".block").hover(function () {
    $(".block").removeClass("hover");
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function () {
    $(".block").removeClass("hover");
    $(this).parent(".block").addClass("hover");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FqKCY/5/

Comment: It works kinda nice, but if you hover on the last ``block`` element you will see that all the others preserve the red font text but drop the ``border-color`` text, how is that?

Comment: Yes, because the `hover` css rule says `color: red;` and that applies to all text in the element and in children of the element. You'd have to set up other rules to override this. For instance adding `.hover .block {color: black;}` would override the children's text color.

Comment: Thank you so much, such an elegant solution (from my understanding).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change the markup a bit. Check this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FqKCY/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block">
                <span>Text</span>
            </div>
            <span>Text</span>
       </div>
       <span>Text</span>
    </div>
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```